# How to validate email as unique while updating data using laravel form request?

Tags: mysql, laravel, validation, laravel-formrequest

I'm using form request to validate data into update method. I'm trying to validate email as a unique value expect requested user email like this

```
 public function rules() {
    $user = $this->user();
    return [
        'name'       => 'required|max:255|string',
        'email'      => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users,email,'.$user->id,
        'restaurant' => 'required',

    ];
}
```

But it doesn't work, how to access requested user id into form request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that you are posting a user object, where `id` is included in your `$request` data.

In case you are storing a new record and email needs to be available, you can use:

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
...
public function rules() {
    return [
        'name'  => 'required|max:255|string',
        'email' => ['required', 'email', 'max:255', Rule::unique('users')],
        'restaurant' => 'required',
    ];
}
```

If you want to ignore your user->id, because you are updating your record and obviously the email is taken by the user:

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
...
public function rules() {
    return [
        'name'  => 'required|max:255|string',
        'email' => ['required', 'email', 'max:255', Rule::unique('users')->ignore($this->id)],
        'restaurant' => 'required',
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case `$this->id` didn't work. But `$this->user` works.

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'first_name' => 'required|min:2|max:150',
        'last_name' => 'required|min:2|max:150',
        'email' => ['required', 'email', 'max:255', Rule::unique('users')->ignore($this->user)]
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone looking for an answer for when $request does not contain any id, for example in a "users/me" request you may use;

```
'email' => ['required', 'email', Rule::unique('users')->ignore(Auth::id())]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Laravel 10 and had to set it up like this:

```
/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array<string, \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\ValidationRule|array|string>
 */
 public function rules(): array
 {
        $userId = optional($this->route('manager'))->id;

        return [
            'firstname' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'lastname' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users,email,'.$userId,
        ];
  }
```